# Is there a deRham (co)homology for vector-valued differential forms?

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology, differential-forms

Is there a deRham (co)homology for vector-valued differential forms?

The deRham (co)homology of differential forms has been well-discussed and well-founded, along with the fact that for the exterior derivative on differential forms, $d$, with $d^2 =0$, then there's a deRham (co)homology.

What about the covariant exterior differential $D$ on vector-valued differential form?  Can a (co)homology be defined?

Comment: I asked a similar question a while back. You may be interested in some of the comments: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/201683/39599

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Yes! And I wasn't able to type in the right search keywords into stackexchange to find your question before answering my question. =p  I read the comments, and they are deeply interesting.  However, it appears that it is still an open and not fully explored question, as I was interested in real-valued manifolds $M$.

Comment: When you say vector-valued, I interpret this as having values in a *fixed* vector space. I presume you're talking about vector-bundle valued forms with non-trivial bundles. Except for flat bundles, you won't have cohomology in any traditional sense, as curvature of the bundle measures the extent to which $D^2\ne 0$. For holomorphic bundles on complex manifolds, Dolbeault cohomology will make sense, since $\bar\partial$ is defined and still has square $0$.

Comment: See [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/6618/69037).